# GridView autofill

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write simple ASP.NET program with a `GridView` element that takes data from a WCF service:

```
GridView1.DataSource = proxy.GetEmoloyeesDetails();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

As a result, the GridView shows me four columns:

```
BirthDate   EmployeeID   FirstName   LastName
```

We can see that the columns are sorted by the first letter.

How to change the order to:

```
EmployeeID   FirstName   LastName   BirthDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [DataColumn.SetOrdinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.setordinal.aspx) method. For example:

```
GridView1.Columns["EmployeeID"].SetOrdinal(0);
GridView1.Columns["FirstName"].SetOrdinal(1);
GridView1.Columns["LastName"].SetOrdinal(2);
GridView1.Columns["BirthDate"].SetOrdinal(3);
```